# ScrollView inside another UIScrollView - delegate

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiscrollview

I have a `UIScrollView` inside another `UIScrollView`. For example:
[image]

This grey area is my device.
Red scrollview is in the background
Yellow scrollview is a subview in red scrollview.

What i want to do is scroll up and down and still have an option to scroll right/left. But when i set delegate to yellow scroll view i cant move right/left. How to handle this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is very easy, you just have to **check** which scrollView you are using to call the delegate method.

In your delegate method:(your delegate method receives a parameter UIScrollView *)scrollView

```
if(scrollView == scrollView1) {

//do stuff for scrollView1 like setContentSize

} else {

//do other stuff

}
```

This is how you control 2 scrollViews with one delegate method.

About what you want to do:

It more be more useful to only make 1 scrollView and set its properties so you scroll to left and right and up and down, two scrollviews are useless and the fact, that they overlay is a problem because the scrollview underneath can not be accessed.

Comment: But my red scrollview is not visible and i can't touch it. How to handle this?

Comment: well, either you use 1 scrollView and adjust the contentSize, or you have to put the scrollviews next to it and not overlay them, you can't use 2 UIScrollViews on the same location.

Comment: You can only add SwipeGestureRecognizer, if it was swiped to left, the left scrollview will be the top view and if you swiped down, the down scrollView is top scrollView